# Running classifiers with cuts on the input arrays (python)

Tags: python, arrays, input, scikit-learn, classification

I wonder if it is possible to run a classifier (e.g. RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier) with the call accepting cuts on the input data.

To make the question more clear, let's say that we want to run

```
gbcl = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=100,
                                  learning_rate=1.0,
                                  max_depth=5,
                                  random_state=1).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

but use only the events for which `X_train[:,3] > 0`.

Is there a way to do this other than creating new input arrays?

Comment: Let's say you are able to pass that information into the classifier. What do you think will happen inside? It will use that info to return a new object (which may be a view of your supplied array). Why don't you want to use a new array like `X_train_new = X_train[X_train[:,3] > 0]`?

Comment: Both for user friendliness and for keeping track better (i.e. not filling the code with a ton of stray arrays while I'm just doing some quick exploration). Actually, I'd expect this to be a sine qua non of any such package: you have only one set with which you work, and you are able to pick parts of it on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of scikit-learn you have to either create a new data like `X_train_new = X_train[X_train[:,3] > 0]`, `y_train_new = y_train[X_train[:,3] > 0]` or, if you want to avoid "filling the code with stray arrays", pass the sliced data directly to the fit method:

```
model.fit(X_train[X_train[:, 3] > 0], y_train[X_train[:, 3] > 0])
```

or

```
b = (X_train[:, 3] > 0)
model.fit(X_train[b], y_train[b])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do using standard `sklearn` capabilities, but you might create a class doing what you want easily (and I would agree it's more readable).

I would personally go for something like this:

```
class SlicingClassifier:
    """Create classifiers of slice data.

    Parameters
    ----------
    classifier : sklearn-compatible classifier
            Classifier with sklearn-compatible interface. Needs fit method.
    slices : array-like[bool] or generator
            List of Boolean numpy arrays able to slice features and targets.
            Can be a generator returning slices.
    """

    def __init__(self, classifier, slices):
        self.classifier_ = classifier
        self.slices_ = slices
        self.models_ = []

    def fit(self, X, y):
        for index_slice in self.slices_:
            self.models_.append(self.classifier_.fit(X[index_slice], y[index_slice]))

        return self

    # You may want to make this a list, but it's more memory-efficient as gen        
    def predict(self, X):
        for model in self.models_:
            yield model.predict(X)
```

You could easily extend this approach with multiple classifiers if so desired, different `predict` method, `fit_transform`, making the API compatible with `sklearn` and so on.

Nice addition (from memory perspective) could be generator `fit_transform` like function if you care only about predictions for each subset of data:

```
def fit_transform_generator(self, X, y):
    for index_slice in self.slices_:
        yield self.classifier_.fit_transform(X[index_slice], y[index_slice])
```

And example calls would go along those lines and would save you from ugly temporary creations of sliced arrays.:

```
classifier = SlicingClassifier(
    GradientBoostingClassifier(
        n_estimators=100, learning_rate=1.0, max_depth=5, random_state=1
    ),
    # Go with your slices however you want, could use generator
    # function as well, even better IMO
    slices=[X > 0, (X ** 3) > X, X[:, 3] != 0],
)

classifier.fit(X, y)
predictions = classifier.predict(X)
```

### Important

Those slices **do not** copy array, they use views and references, so no additional memory needed (except arrays which slice the original `X`).

### Slices as generator

Instead of passing slices as `List` you could use a generator object as well (for many slicing indices you should use this approach).

Example provided to clear confusion:

```
def slices_generator(X, stop, start=0, step=1):
    for i in range(start, stop, step):
        yield X < i

classifier = SlicingClassifier(
    GradientBoostingClassifier(
        n_estimators=100, learning_rate=1.0, max_depth=5, random_state=1
    ),
    slices=slices_generator(X, 1000),
)
```

Comment: Interesting, but I don't see how this is better from simply calling e.g. `classifier.fit(X[X > 0], y[X > 0])`. Your approach seems more confusing because you always call `classifier.fit(X, y)` something that hides the fact that in reality you could be using sliced X and y.

Comment: Readability-wise it's better and you can save some typing (though it might need adjustments for OP's exact use case). And yeah, it hides the implementation, as is usually the case with higher-level objects, but it's name `SlicingClassifier` makes it pretty obvious (along with ~10 lines implementation). There is no need for `X[X>0]` and explicit slicing, and I think that's what OP is after, citing comment: `Both for user friendliness and for keeping track better (i.e. not filling the code with a ton of stray arrays while I'm just doing some quick exploration).`

Comment: Oh, and if you have a process generating slices of data, you don't have to keep those in memory (say there are 10.000 of boolean arrays slicing original data, each of size 100 x 100), just pass the function into `slices` argument. So it has it's advantages __if this process is repeated many times__.

Comment: Aren't the slicing boolean arrays such as `X > 0` etc. stored in `classifier.slices_` ? This seems to unnecessary consume memory.

Comment: You can easily pass `generator object` as `slices` argument in constructor, hence no memory overhead. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think that for "quick work" the other given answer is more suitable, but this one is something for learning (and probably using in factory-grade runs).